# In React native yarn start is not working in cmd

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I am new in react native so help me starting with it,
when i type yarn start in cmd it shows me that error

```
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have no idea where i have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In react native, you have to run the app either on android or ios by running these commands.

```
react-native run-android
OR
react-native run-ios
```